# QML binding item issue

Tags: qt, binding, qml, qt-quick

I have problem in binding item in QML, for example:

```
Rectangle{
    id: thetarget
    width:100
    height:100
}
Item{
    id: container
    MouseArea{            
        id:mousearea
        drag.target: thetarget  //not work        
        anchors.fill: thetarget  //not work
        property int foo: thetarget.width  //work
    }
}
```

What I want is to make the bindings for drag.target, anchors.fill work without changing the structure (mousearea is not the sibling or child of thetarget). I have used Binding, function to return thetarget, but they are all useless. Could someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: i think you should put MouseArea under thetarget element, why you want to put it under container and bind it to thetarget ?

Comment: I want to make an independent component and pass an item (eg. thetarget) to its API. That component may be Item, Loader, or Rectangle...which contains a MouseArea that can be used to drag the passed item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the parent of the `mousearea` to `thetarget`.

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Item {
    Rectangle {
        id: thetarget
        width: 100
        height: 100
    }
    Item {
        id: container
        MouseArea {
            id: mousearea
            parent: thetarget
            drag.target: thetarget
            anchors.fill: thetarget
            property int foo: thetarget.width
        }
    }
}
```